# Call to a member function render_social_icons() on a non-object

Tags: php, wordpress

i have received a Fatal error from logs its repeating same error.
I don,t understand what to do please help me out on this.
Eroor logs:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function render_social_icons() on a
>   non-object in content-single.php on line 190

Code :

```
<div class="fusion-sharing-box share-box"> 
<h4>
<?php echo __('Share This Story, Choose Your Platform!', 'Avada'); ?></h4> 
<?php 
echo $social_icons->render_social_icons( $sharingbox_soical_icon_options ); 
?>
```

Comment: and the php code is
Line 188 <div class="fusion-sharing-box share-box">
Line 189 <h4><?php echo __('Share This Story, Choose Your Platform!', 'Avada'); ?></h4>
Line 190 <?php echo $social_icons->render_social_icons( $sharingbox_soical_icon_options ); ?>

Comment: can you please tell me which plugin are you using or put code of you render social_icons

Comment: you are using theme fusion right??

Comment: no we are using theme avada

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: @Kuanl you have to check you functions.php file there is same thing is available.this code is not enough to understand problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of class then use it in cotent-single.php file.Before that you have to include file for that specific class.

```
$social_icons= new <Some class>;
$social_icons->render_social_icons( $sharingbox_soical_icon_options );
```

You have to share `cotent-single.php` that will give more idea.

Answer (score 0):

`$social_icons` isn't what you're expecting it to be.

You're treating `$social_icons` as an object when you try to call the `render_social_icons()` method and it's generating an error because it isn't one.

Where are you defining `$social_icons`? Was the code copied/pasted from elsewhere? Without seeing more code it's difficult to help devise a solution beyond suggesting that you trace it back and find out where `$social_icons` is being defined.